# OVERLAY ERROR - MEDIA PROCESSOR NOT CREATED

Tags: blackberry, overlay

while trying to overlay an image in blackberry i am getting this error

```
Image outerFrame = Image.createImage("/outerFrame.png");
Image innerFrame = Image.createImage("/innerFrame.png");
OverlayControl overlay = myMediaProcessor.getControl ("javax.microedition.media.control.imageeffect.OverlayControl");
overlay.insertImage(innerFrame, 0,0,1); // order = 1
overlay.insertImage(outerFrame, 0,0,0); // order = 0
```

I can’t get to create “myMediaProcessor”.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show a lot of context, so it's hard to understand what you're actually asking for.

`myMediaProcessor` should be an object of a class that implements the

```
javax.microedition.media.Controllable
```

interface. See the [Controllabale javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Controllable.html#getControl%28java.lang.String%29) for a list of classes that implement it.

Alternatively, look at the javadoc for the [MediaProcessor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/amms/MediaProcessor.html) interface, and the [GlobalManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/amms/GlobalManager.html) docs. These have the information you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Hi Mat,i am trying to use overlay concept the above is the default code that i found online,when i tried implementing it i am getting error at                                                                      MediaProcessor myMediaProcessor = null;                                               OverlayControl overlay = myMediaProcessor.getControl ("javax.microedition.media.control.imageeffect.OverlayControl");             ERROR: cannot convert from Control to OverlayControl